# Need to resize the Canvas div like textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Need to resize(draggable) the canvas div. ()

I have tried below code:

```
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>

.canvas
{

border: 1px solid;

resize: both;

overflow: auto;

}
```

The same code working for div element, But for canvas element its not working.

Is it possible for resize the canvas element like textarea?

Answer (score 2):

Canvas seems to not be resizable this way.

But you can put it in a div:

```css
div
{

  border: red 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;

  height: 100px; 
  width:200px; margin:10px;padding:10px;
  
}

canvas{

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border: green 1px solid;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  border: red 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
  height: 100px; 
  width:200px;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
}

canvas {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border: green 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```